# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_17 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 256, 256, 3)

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, keras, anaconda, image-recognition

I was constructing a CNN to predict human age based on VGG-16, and feeding two RGB images. (filetype: jpg). I was using tensorflow backend in anaconda environment with Python 2.7.

However, it always raises an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "train2.py", line 167, in 
>       shuffle=True)
>
> File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/keras/models.py",line 973, in fit validation_steps=validation_steps)
>
> File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1581, in fit batch_size=batch_size)
>
> File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1418, in _standardize_user_data exception_prefix='target')
>
> File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/keras/engine/training.py", line 141, in _standardize_input_data str(array.shape))
>
> ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_17 to
>
> have 2  dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 256, 256, 3)

How can I solve this error? Here is the code:

```
import keras

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense

from keras.layers import Dropout

from keras.layers import Activation

from keras.layers import Flatten

from keras.layers import Conv2D

from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D

from keras.layers import BatchNormalization

from keras.utils import np_utils

import cv2

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

name_path = ["pathname"]

new_age_list=[45,52]

img_rows=256

img_cols=256

img_array = 
np.array([np.array(Image.open(i).resize((img_rows,img_cols),Image.BILINEAR)) for i in name_path[0:2]],"f")

(X, y) = (img_array[0:2],new_age_list[0:2])

y=np.asarray(y)

X=X.reshape(2,256,256,3)

# STEP 1: split X and y into training and testing sets

train_data, train_label,test_data, test_label= train_test_split(X, y, 
test_size=0.5, random_state=4)

train_data = train_data.astype('float32')

test_data = test_data.astype('float32')

train_data = train_data / 255

test_data = test_data / 255

""" Model """

model = Sequential()

""" Block 1 """

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', 
border_mode='valid',input_shape=(256,256,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

""" Block 2 """

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

""" Block 3 """

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

""" Block 4 """
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

""" Block 5 """

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))

""" Flatten """

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(128))

model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(32))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Activation('softmax'))

""" Optimizer """

opt = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=config.learning_rate, 

decay=config.decay)

print model.summary()

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=
['accuracy'])

""" Fit Data """

batch_size = 512

epoch = 1000

learning_rate = 1e-4

decay = 1e-7

for i in range(epoch):

    model.fit(train_data, train_label,

              batch_size=batch_size,

              epochs=int(epoch/epoch),

              validation_data=(test_data, test_label),

              shuffle=True)
```

Comment: please format your code as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

also please be more descriptive on what platforms you are using and tag them accordingly

Comment: @raurunner Thanks for your help in arranging the code!

Comment: Could somebody check this for me? It's kind of urgent. I have to demo it next week...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume "activation_17" refers to the last activation layer, which is the "softmax" layer. As your image propagates through the layers without problems, I assume there is a problem with the dimensions of your labels.

After checking the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`, it seems you made a mistake assigning the return values from `train_test_split()`.

Try it like so:

```
train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label= train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=4)
```

Comment: Yeah! It seems to work! Though it raises another error, I think it's just the improper CNN structure error. I can solve it myself. Thank you so much:)

Comment: @NickChao if the answer was satisfactory please consider accepting it.